# What does "while" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

What does *while* mean in the following sentence? Is this the same as "while I like blue, Henry likes red"?

> The Border Defense Cooperation Agreement would be aimed at avoiding armed conflict while the actual lines of the border are agreed to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in this case it means "at the same time as" or "during the time that".  Your example has more the meaning of "although".